# Cookie or Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, cookies

I am trying to make a countdown timer for a game. And the problem is, when the user move to another page, then countdown cannot continue the remaining time. I am trying to set a cookie and session, but I have no idea about it.

Comment: Do you have any sample code to point us in a direction? Here's a countdown script that may do the work for you - http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html

Comment: And here's a good link to start with cookies: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html combine this with the previous comment and you should be good to go!

Comment: I didn't have the sample code... But I have figured another way out.. Thanks all...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cookies are sent back and forth with every HTTP request, hence should be avoided for storing unnecessary variables.

To maintain the timer on the server-side, a session is the best choice. It will take care of the cookie business automatically, creating only the bare-minimum cookie overhead to keep track of the session. Session variables live on the server, and are connected to HTTP requests by unique cookies.

Regarding your countdown timer: Since you cannot keep a function running on the server to keep flipping the bits, the best bet is to keep track of the end time.

To initiate a session in PHP, use `session_start()`. Then store your values in `$_SESSION[]` array, and they'll persist across requests. Here's an example:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['endTime']))
{
    $_SESSION['endTime'] = time() + 60; // end time is 60 seconds from now
    echo "Started a new timer"
}
else if ($_SESSION['endTime'] > time())
{
    echo "Time left: " + ($_SESSION['endTime'] - time());
}
else
{
    echo "Time is up.";
}
```

Comment: I might suggesr a correction to your code There should not be ! in the second if it should be else if ($_SESSION['endTime'] > time())
sho time