# How to set time out for tech quiz in PHP or Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, timeout

I'm developing a script for technical quiz which is going to have MCQ types questions (1 question at a time). I want to set time out of 20 mins to each user. After twenty minutes the user should be signed out. The page is going to be reloaded for every new question.

Should I set timeout in PHP or JavaScript? How can I set timeout to to do particular task?

I also want to show the time remaining, and decrease it every second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a cookie named loggedin. PHP code: `setcookie("loggedin", $username, time()+1200);`

Then check if `$_COOKIE["loggedin"]` is set. If not, then user is not logged in.

Edit: look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251336/cookie-or-javascript), it gives some basic recommandations which you could follow with some extra javascript and ajax code

Edit2: perhaps you could try an IP-based solution, but some internet providers could cause problem: as far as I know, some change IP **very** frequently. If you use this, MySQL is required as well.

Comment: And if the user is blocking cookies or deletes their cookies then what?

Comment: I forget to mansion. i want to show timeout !! time decreasing on every second.

Comment: @j08691: is there ANYONE on the Earth who blocks cookies? Chaitanya: this has to be done with javascript. Use this answer and explode: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8249225/1176812 with PHP. Then, with AJAX, get this, and pass it to javascript. Then, look up a timer code. There are plenty of tutorials on each problems, if you can't find any good, I'll link some.

Comment: @j08691 Yes, there is. You must never assume.

Comment: @axiomer - Of course there are. And if I'm taking a quick and realize that cookies are what's keeping track of my time, well then it's easy to get past that minor hurdle. Truth - I assume your comment was for axoim?

Comment: You could be right. I misinterpreted "should be signed out" as that after inactivity, they'll have to login again, but continue from the same place and time is used for only that.

Comment: ok fine with cookie.. But what about showing timeout.. User should know how much time he have. Time out should be displayed !!please help

Comment: Here's a simple javascript countdown: http://stuntsnippets.com/javascript-countdown/ You'll have to change time_left to a result of an AJAX query: you could perhaps use jquery's AJAX or XMLHTTPRequest.

Answer (score 0):

I am not into PHP but I think the best approach is a combination of server side and client side techniques. On the client side I would use a cookie. But in the server I would keep a start time on the session so that you can validate at the server as well. If you want to show the timeout, javascript has timing functions that you can use:http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp. on each tick you can update your label.